# why won't this Closure attempted with Python work?

Tags: python-2.7, closures

This prints something:

```
def foo(message):
    print(message)

foo("baba booey")
```

[Python Tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20foo(message%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print(message%29%0A%0Afoo(%22baba%20booey%22%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Why doesn't this print anything:

```
def foo(message):
    def bar():
        print(message)

foo("baba booey")
```

[Python Tutor link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20foo(message%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20bar(%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(message%29%0A%0Afoo(%22baba%20booey%22%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Per [this tutorial](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures), they should both work.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It does exactly what you've asked it to. It doesn't crash. You just never return or execute the function you created.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I meant was it doesn't seem to print anything. I am going to clarify it in an update.

Comment: You should re-read the tutorial, you aren't doing the same thing it does and have no reason to expect the second snippet to print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a return statement in the `foo` function to return the `bar` function:

```
def foo(message):
    def bar():
        print(message)
    return bar #<-- have to return bar function

ret = foo("baba booey") #<-- ret is now the bar function
ret #<-- again returns the bar function but doesn't execute it
ret() #<-- executes the bar function and prints "baba booey"
```

currently you are not calling `bar` anywhere in the code, even though `foo` is getting called. You can check this by:

```
def foo(message):
    print("In foo before bar")
    def bar():
        print(message)
    print("In foo after bar")
    bar()
    print("Just called bar from within foo")

foo("baba booey")
```

Comment: Still not working? Python Tutor link: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20foo(message%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20bar(%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(message%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20bar%20%23%3C--%20have%20to%20return%20bar%20function%0A%0A%0Afoo(%22baba%20booey%22%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: when you call `foo("baba booey")` it is returning the `bar` function, not executing it. So you need to capture the return value of `foo("baba booey")` and execute it as so: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20foo(message%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20bar(%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(message%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20bar%20%23%3C--%20have%20to%20return%20bar%20function%0A%0A%0Aret%20%3D%20foo(%22baba%20booey%22%29%0Aret(%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=10&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false